# My legend in r is not showing. What could be the issue?

Tags: r, plot

This is my code, it works so far, except that the legend does not appear in the plot:

```
plot(norm_prices_daily[,1], col = "blue",lwd=3,grid.col = NA, ylim = c(0,3))
lines(norm_prices_daily[,2],lwd=3, col = "dark green")
legend("bottomright",legend=c("Stock 1","Stock 2"),col = c("blue","dark green"))
```

norm_prices_daily is a zoo object with two columns and 182 rows.
Here is part of the data. Output from dput(head(norm_prices_daily[,1],20)):

```
structure(c(1, 0.9929401294387, 0.99644855697716, 0.9936552740678, 
0.998526620668352, 1.00517207744161, 1.00230213170477, 1.00929440707496, 
1.00776579745506, 1.0096505179963, 1.01809781273736, 1.02202987149226, 
1.01931947115634, 1.01961413204347, 1.0207774879027, 1.01154745364837, 
0.99563509229331, 1.0056447937894, 1.00477302623885, 1.00792234548049
), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1600533381.35332, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), index = structure(c(1577923200, 1578009600, 1578268800, 
1578355200, 1578441600, 1578528000, 1578614400, 1578873600, 1578960000, 
1579046400, 1579132800, 1579219200, 1579564800, 1579651200, 1579737600, 
1579824000, 1580083200, 1580169600, 1580256000, 1580342400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(20L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "^GSPC"))
```

I have tried different options for the position of the legend, such as specific x and y coordinates, because I suspected that the legend is there but just too low or something. But that does not seem to the issue.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a reproducible question with representative sample data. Consider either replicating your process using a common dataset like `iris` or `mtcars`, or including the output from `dput(head(x,n))` where `x` is your dataset (with only the required columns) and `n` is a number large enough to be able to reproduce your problem but not "large"; depending on many things, `n=10` or `n=20` is often big enough.

Comment: When I try to replicate the error with the iris data set, the error doesn't occur (the legend shows up as it should). 
I've edited my question with my data.

Comment: Your code throws errors on the first line since `grid.col = NA` is not a valid graphical parameter and on the second line because there is no column 2 in your data.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the kind of line you want in the legend, but it should still print the labels. Here is a slight modification of the first example on the manual page for `print.zoo` to make it more comparable to yours:

```
x.Date <- as.Date(paste(2003, 02, c(1, 3, 7, 9, 14), sep = "-"))
set.seed(42)
x <- zoo(cbind(rnorm(5), rnorm(5, sd= 0.2)), x.Date)
plot(x[, 1], col = "blue")
lines(x[, 2], col = "dark green")
legend("bottomright", legend=c("Stock 1","Stock 2"), lty=1, col = c("blue","dark green"))
```

[image: Plot]